# DJANGO - Como pasar un objeto de una vista a otra vista distinta

Tags: django

Tengo el siguiente modelo:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
nif = models.CharField('DNI/NIF', max_length=11)
name = models.CharField('Nombre', max_length=50)
comercial = models.ForeignKey(Comercial, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Cliente'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Clientes'

def __str__(self):
    return self.nif + ':' + self.name_fiscal
```

Tengo una aplicación. Cliente.

```
class ClienteView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
template_name = 'Clientes/add.html'
form_class = ClienteForm
success_url = '../videoadd/'  

def form_valid(self, form):
    nif_f = form.cleaned_data['nif']
    name_f = form.cleaned_data['name']

    datos_comercial = Comercial.objects.get(name = comercial_f)
    
    Cliente.objects.create(
        nif = nif_f,
        name = name_f,
        comercial = datos_comercial
    )

    return super(ClienteView, self).form_valid(form)
```

un formulario:

```
class ClienteForm(forms.Form):
nif = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
comercial = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

con su template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <H3>Datos del Cliente</H3>
    <p>NIF: {{ form.nif }}</p>
    <p>Nombre: {{ form.name }}</p>
    <p>Comercial: {{ form.comercial }}</p>
    <button type="submit">Siguiente</button>
</form>
```

**necesito que cuando pulse en el botón del template Siguiente y se cree el cliente en la base de datos este objeto cliente pase a otra vista video (creada de la misma forma).
Hay alguna forma de poder hacer?**
Gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.